# android response.getHeaders("Location");

Tags: android, response

I was trying to get URL from shortened URL with below codes on ANDROID.
so If you have any idea please help me~~

There are many comments about "`response.getHeaders("Location")`; will work~"
but I don't think **getHeaders("Location")** would work

Is there any other way to get Long URL...?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
HttpClient myclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://goo.gl/XNK93Q";
HttpGet myget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = myclient.execute(myget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

for(Header header : response.getHeaders("Location")) {
     System.out.println("Location from connect:" + header.getValue());
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: And you don't think it will work because...?

Comment: Because I coded and ran it.. so I can see that it doesn't work...